# Get data from CSV to delete users folders from multiple servers

Tags: powershell, csv

I am very new to powershell and situation is that I have some unneeded users folder that must be deleted on different servers. Path on all servers is f.e. "\server1\hiddenshare$\username" My CSV looks like:

```
ServerName,FolderName
SERVER1,AAAA
SERVER2,AAA1
SERVER3,AAA2
```

And I am trying to run this code:

```
$path = "C:\temp\servers_folders.csv"
$ServerName = Import-Csv -Path $path
$FolderName = Import-CSV -Path $path
Import-Csv -Path $path | % {
  Remove-Item -Path \\$ServerName\hiddenshare$\$FolderName -Recurse
    }
```

After all I get this error:

```
Remove-Item : Cannot find path '\\  \$\  ' because it does not exist.
At C:\temp\servers_folders.csv.ps1:5 char:3
+   Remove-Item -Path \\$ServerName\hiddenshare$\$FolderName -Recurse
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\  \usr$\  :String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need to import your csv more than once.
Inside the foreach block you have to reference the current item by `$_`

try this, remove -whatif if it's ok

```
$servers=import-csv .\servers.csv

$servers | %{
    remove-item -path \\$($_.servername)\users$\$($_.FolderName) -whatif
}
```